# Django-Rest-Framework dynamic url (dynamic prefix)

Tags: regex, django, rest, django-rest-framework

i have historic data that i want to publish via webservice by versions. To do that i'm using Django-Rest-Framework. I'm already using this framework to provide other services but now it seems to be a little bit harder to accomplished this goal.

The main goal is to provide a url:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/vocab (realtime) - done
http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/v1/vocab (version 1)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/v2/vocab (version 2)
http://127.0.0.1:8000/service/vn/vocab (version n)
```

for this i'm trying to config the DRF router to make this possible.

So the idea is something like this:

**urls.py**

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'vocab', views.VocabViewSet, 'vocabs')
router.register(r'{version}/vocab', views.VersionViewSet, 'vocab')

    urlpatterns = patterns('',
    ...
        url(r'^service/', include(router.urls))


)
```

**views.py**

```
class VersionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
        queryset = Version.objects.all()
        serializer_class = VersionSerializer

        @detail_route(methods=['post'], url_path='vocab')
            def get_vocabs(self, request, version='v1'):
            queryset = Version.objects.filter(version=version)
```

In this case it occurs :

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'version'
```

That's because that DRF expects an int after `service/`.

I'm trying to find a solution to this case. Can you provide any hint how can i make this ?

Maybe [Customize dynamic routes](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers/#customizing-dynamic-routes) is the a good approach, what do you think ? If so, can you provide an example how to apply it in this case or similar?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer to this is URL versioning, which is automatically supported by Django Rest Framework. You can find all the details you need here:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/

In your particular case, you'd want to use the `URLPathVersioning`. You can start by adding this key-value pair to your `REST_FRAMEWORK` settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_VERSIONING_CLASS': 'rest_framework.versioning.URLPathVersioning'
}
```

then, configure your `urls.py` similar to this:

http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/versioning/#urlpathversioning

Answer (score 0):

You can have a url folder with multiple files in it (`__init__.py`, `urls_api_1_0.py` and `urls_api_1_0.py`).
Basically one file for every API version and your `__init__.py` file. Which routes your different API versions. See code below

```
import urls_api_1_0
import urls_api_2_0

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^api/v1/', include(urls_api_1_0)),
    url(r'^api/v2/', include(urls_api_2_0)),
)

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
urlpatterns += format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns, allowed=['json', 'html'])
```

Your `urls_api_1_0.py` could look something like this

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
import package.views.api_2_0 as views

urlpatterns = \
patterns('',
         url(r'^ vocab/$', views.VocabListView.as_view(),
             name='all-vocab-v2'),
         )
```

Comment: This is not dynamic. If you in backoffice define a third version? How you will define? you will have to go to urls.py and define a new url pattern?